# how to extract and check if first character in array element is a letter

Tags: c++, c

Does anyone know how i could go about extracting and checking if the very first character in my char array is an alphabet, i need to do this without using isalpha, is this even possible?

char* spellCheck[] = {"babi", "cmopuertr", "3method"};

i have something like that and i need to be able to extract the 3 in the 3rd element in that character array such that the word will count as spelled correctly!

PLease Help

Thnx

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know how to check the first char in a string not in an array?

Comment: Is 'é' an alphabet for you? Because I think most answers suppose that a letter (or an alphabet) is a-z or A-Z only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha):

> Checks if the given character is an alphabetic character [...]

Example:

```
#include <cctype> // for std::isalpha

if ( std::isalpha( str[0] ) )
    std::cout << "The character is an alphabetic character." << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe with `isalpha(my_string[0])` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <cctype>

bool b = std::isalpha(thearray[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `isalpha()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>  //header file required for isalpha(); function

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "Test";
        /* I cast the array element to an integer since the isalpha function calls for
           an integer as a parameter
        */

    if(isalpha((int) string[0])) printf("first array element is a character"); 
    else printf("first array element not a character");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can use the library function `isalpha`.

```
int isalpha(int c);  //c is the character to be checked
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use isalpha() method in C

```
int isalpha ( int c );
```

other ways you can use if condition check for the ascii codes for a-z and A-Z

Comment: thanks, is aplha did the trick.